# nodejs file changes not reflecting even nodemon & supervisor

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I have setup & run this project https://github.com/achowba/node-mysql-crud-app. it is working fine but after changes in any file not reflecting at front end, always front output remain same as previous.

Showing following output when `nodemon app.js`

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\node-mysql-crud-app>nodemon app.js
[nodemon] 2.0.2
[nodemon] reading config .\nodemon.json
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] or send SIGHUP to 5896 to restart
[nodemon] ignoring: .\.git/**/* node_modules/**/node_modules
[nodemon] watching dir(s): app.js routes\**\* views\**\*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,json,ejs
[nodemon] bind restart -> `osascript -e 'display notification "App restarted due to:
'$FILENAME'" with title "nodemon"'`
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
[nodemon] forking
[nodemon] child pid: 1692
[nodemon] watching 7 files
Server running on port: 2000
Connected to database
```

My nodemon.json file

```
{
  "restartable": "rs",
  "ignore": [
    ".git",
    "node_modules/**/node_modules"
  ],
  "verbose": true,
  "execMap": {
    "js": "node"
  },
  "events": {
    "restart": "osascript -e 'display notification \"App restarted due to:\n'$FILENAME'\" with title \"nodemon\"'"
  },
  "watch": [
    "app.js",
    "routes/",
    "views/"
  ],
  "env": {
    "NODE_ENV": "development"
  },
  "ext": "js,json,ejs"
}
```

My directory like following

[image]

**I have tried also `supervisor` but same issue. hard cache clear  also tried but no reflection. please help what I can do now**

Comment: which file did you change??

Comment: @SaadSohail almost each file I have changed for testing, no reflection

Comment: it is working fine files are rendering for me !!! i have made changes to the sql and it is working

Comment: @SaadSohail Even I have empty the app.js file & tried by run nodemon again but no effect

Comment: made changes to the mysql variable , add your sql database name then it works

Comment: @SaadSohail this is later, first I need to find out why my app.js, index.ejs etc file change not taking effect

Answer (score 0):

Finally it is solved. It was netbeans IDE issue. When I edit in notepad++ then change reflect but in netbeans not worked. Dont know why netbenas not worked. I have deleted & created again this project. After that even not able to create new project in netbeans now for this project